# View a PDF file in HTML not to download it

Tags: html, pdf

I have a very simple pure html file in which I have many PDF files. I have link it like this:

```
<a href="pdffile.pdf"> PDF 1 here </a>
```

When I click the link, the PDF file is downaloaded and viewed in the native Reader program. I want it to open in another window of the browser, and read it there, rather then saving a copy manually to my computer and opening it.

Comment: Seems this is a known problem for Chrome. Are you seeing the same problems elsewhere too? For Chrome fix you can use this https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/nnbmlagghjjcbdhgmkedmbmedengocbn

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### 2018 Update

Almost all modern browsers have built-in PDF viewers. You can directly link to the PDF file and the browser will view it. You can also use an `<iframe>` if you want to view it inside an HTML page (e.g. with your website headers, etc.).

Another approach, but more complicated and not necessary except for very special circumstances, is to convert the PDF files to HTML (as described in #1 of the 2012 answer below).

#### Original Answer (Outdated, from 2012)

Viewing the PDF file in the browser (without download) requires an add-on to the client's browser. Google Chrome, for example, has a built-in PDF viewer and can open files directly, while IE and Firefox require that you install a plug-in (the one that comes with Adobe Reader).

There are two other approaches:

1. Convert the file to HTML, image, or any other format that can be directly viewed in the browser. This conversion can be on-the-fly using a server-side (written in PHP, Python, ASP, whatever language), or you can just pre-convert all files to a readable one.
2. The other approach, which is the best, is to use a Flash-based PDF viewer (such as http://flexpaper.devaldi.com/). This is easy, flexible and doesn't require writing server-side code. This approach is used by many Document-sharing sites (e.g. http://www.scribd.com/, http://www.slideshare.net/, http://www.docstoc.com/)

Comment: I think this answer has the closest solution to my problem. Thanks @Aziz

Comment: In 2018, a Flash-based anything is never the best.

Comment: @FrankSeifert: That answer was in 2012 .. Flash was a thing back then :) I'll update it

Answer (score 4):

i use this

for the HTML

```
<a href="view.php?download_file=MIKOGO Remote Support.pdf"><img src="images/view.png" alt=" " border="0"/></a>
```

and the view.php file for viewing it through PDF.

```
<?php

$path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/demo/documents/"; // change the path to fit your websites document structure
$fullPath = $path.$_GET['download_file'];

if ($fd = fopen ($fullPath, "r")) {
$fsize = filesize($fullPath);
$path_parts = pathinfo($fullPath);
$ext = strtolower($path_parts["extension"]);
switch ($ext) {
    case "pdf":
    header("Content-type: application/pdf"); // add here more headers for diff. extensions
    header("Content-Disposition: inline; filename=\"".$path_parts["basename"]."\"");     
    break;
    default;
    header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
    header("Content-Disposition: filename=\"".$path_parts["basename"]."\"");
}
header("Content-length: $fsize");
header("Cache-control: private"); //use this to open files directly
while(!feof($fd)) {
    $buffer = fread($fd, 2048);
    echo $buffer;
}
}
fclose ($fd);
exit;
?>
```

Make sure the your browser has PDF add-on on it.

Answer (score 4):

Mozilla created the [PDF.js](https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/) library.  It displays pdf files in a web page without an external reader or plugin.

Answer (score 1):

Your browser needs a PDF reader plug in to read PDFs in browser. A quick google search should provide you with one for whatever browser you are using.

Answer (score 0):

If the file is not cached, it has to be downloaded. That is, if you grab it using HTTP. If it's on your local filesystem, you could use the [file URI scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_URI_scheme).

Comment: He means he wants it to display in the browser, and not downloaded and viewed by Adobe Reader.

Comment: Judging by the other answers and votes, you're right. But then his question should read something like "how to have a PDF open in a browser window, not in another app". It is not that obvious what he means.

Comment: You're right, it's not obvious. I've edited the question to elaborate.

Answer (score -1):

right click
Open with
Choose default programme
Select
Adobe Reader
OK
If you want open chrome any other app
Same steps
Last Step
Select
Chrome

Comment: right click on the file before opening    Click  Open with Click to Choose default programme Select Adobe Reader Click OK button If you want open chrome any other app Same steps Last Step Select Chrome

Comment: you can edit your answer and add more information there instead of commenting.

Answer (score -1):

I was facing the same issue and scoured the internet for an answer.
I am here to provide that answer in case future HTML-learners come across this thread too, wondering the same thing.

```
<embed src="document_name.pdf" style="width: 123px; height: 123px;">
```

You could always have the style settings in a separate CSS file and link them to this element but whatever. Now go forth and create websites!